# What Facebook permission am I missing that is causing this simple request to not work?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have two users (**user_1** & **user_2**) authenticated with my app.

The two users have different permissions allowed for the app.

Both users are friends with **other_user**.

When I try to get the content at this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/other_user/posts/10150177165252500
```

It works for **user_1**, but not for **user_2**. **user_2** gets

```
resp=false
```

Here are the permissions for **user_1**, who can get the content:

[image]
[image]

Here are the permissions for **user_2**, who can NOT get the content:
[image]

What permission does **user_1** have that allows them to get the content, that **user_2** does not have?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, both users can SEE the content through the Facebook webpage.

Comment: double check if you're using the correct access_token for user_2.

Comment: @dragonjet - I am, because user_2 can get their own wall posts. Should have included that in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a big list with lots of differences - however, what stands out to me is that for **user_1**, the permission for **`Access my friends' information`** has subtext that reads *Birthdays, Religious and Political Views, Family Members and...See More* while **user_2**'s has only *Activities*. That seems like the most likely candidate there.

---

If this doesn't fix it then some other questions you might want to answer in your post:

1. What permissions *did* your app request to begin with?
2. Why are the user's permissions different? Did **user_2** authorize the app and then revoke some permissions?
3. Have you tried trimming down **user_1**'s permissions one by one? When you find the one that stops **user_1** from seeing the content also, you've got your answer.
4. What does the Facebook documentation say about this - what permissions are required to get friends' posts?

Comment: This was it, thanks for your help. I needed the friends_status permission, got confused because the permissions page states that it 'Provides access to the user's most recent status message', not all statuses. But in actual fact is can get all statuses.